# Image leakout from div

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web I have some `divs`. The first and the top one is my menu bar and below that one I have another `div`. The second `div` contain photo change and below him a `div` with some text. When I running my code the photos(which locate in the second div) cover all the `divs` (although the menu bar position is "fixed"). I think that the problem is somewhere in the `css` file. can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">בית</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">אודות</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">עבודות</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">פרוייקטים</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">חיפויי קירות</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">צרו קשר</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main_pics" class="container">
<!-- photos here -->
<div id="main_photo1" class="phocont first">
    <p>1</p>
</div>
<div id="main_photo2" class="phocont">
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div id="main_photo3" class="phocont">
    <p>3</p>
</div>
<div id="main_photo4" class="phocont">
    <p>4</p>
</div>
<div id="main_photo5" class="phocont">
    <p>5</p>
</div>
```

here is my css code:

```
#main_pics {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}

.phocont {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
text-align:center;
}
.phocont p {
margin-top:30%;
font-size:60pt;
color:#fff;
text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
 }
.first {
z-index:9999;
}
#image{
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}

#main_photo1{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url("1.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}

#main_photo2{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-image: url("2.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}

#main_photo3{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-image: url("3.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
}

.container{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
}
```

[jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/54qcm7tL/)

Comment: A JSFiddle would help.

Comment: main_pics div didn't close..

Comment: your `main` height of 100% is overwriting your `.container` height of 500px so this will be why you are covering the text below the main div (I'm guessing you haven't set any height style for the parent of main so 100% of nothing will be zero causing the absolute positioned elements to "leak out").  As you have said your header is fixed, IO'm guessing this will be under the main container as you haven't set any z-indexes.  But without more code to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this is all pure guess work

Comment: i didnt get what you trying to say, can you show by fixing the code?

Comment: Would be good if you produce a fiddle..

Comment: You haven't given enough code to fix, have a look at the link in my last comment.  You say you have issues with the header but you haven't even provided any css for the header so how can I fix something when you haven't even supplied all the code?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqwvv6nq/) \  note that the images cantbe load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/54qcm7tL/1/) as an example. You need to specify a height for your fixed header and give it the property `top:0` in order to keep it fixed at the top. this will also remove the fixed element from the flow of your page so you will have to give your photo `div` a top margin to position it below the header. I'm not sure about the text you have after the photos as you did not provide the information needed.

*EDIT*

After reviewing your recent comment you should change `main_pics` to this:

```
#main_pics {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
position:relative;
margin-top:55px;
z-index:1;
}
```

and also add `z-index:2;` to `#nav_bar`